# Why does std::cin's extractor operator wait for user input?

Tags: c++, input, buffer, cin

I know that this may be a stupid question but I am not sure how getting user input from the terminal actually works.

I understand input/output conceptually and I have no problem using them but I am lost when it comes to how these are actually implemented at a basic level.

As far as I know all stream objects use a type of buffer. If you extract all the characters you reach eof. It's this part I am probably wrong and I would like to know more about. For instance when we use the std::cin's extractor operator, it waits for input. How does it differentiate between waiting for input and reaching eof (nothing else to read) ?

Comment: reaching eof would set the eof bit (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) - waiting for input wouldn't.

Comment: conceptually I would not say that it waits for input... instead it pulls the first available input from the buffer that you mentioned... if the buffer is empty it hangs waiting for an available value (the effect being that it waits for input when the buffer is empty)... at least that was my understanding of std:cin

Comment: @user3334690 That's not quite right.  In will call into the systems read command, with the address and the size of a buffer.  Whether it is reading a file or a keyboard makes no difference.  The system will then return when it wants, depending on the type of device the handle or file descriptor designates.

Comment: @JamesKanze ah, so it is the system that hangs until it can fill the buffer? that makes sense...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::cin` doesn't do anything special.  Like all file input, it
emits a system level read (`read` in Unix, `ReadFile` in
Windows), for enough bytes to fill its buffer (usually something
well over 1K today).  It is the system which detects that the
input is from a keyboard, and behaves differently: from a file,
the system will read as many bytes as are available, up to the
end of file or the number requested, and return immediately.
From the keyboard, the system will normally read the characters
into an internal buffer until enter, to allow editing (back
space, etc.), and only on enter will it pass this buffer back to
the caller (after having appended the new line marker).

EDIT:

Sort of as a summary as to elements mentionned in the
discussion: I'll take as an example what happens in a Unix
system (but Windows is basically the same, modulo the way it
reports the different information).  The `istream` itself is
buffered.  When you try to extract a character (an `>>`
operator, `istream::get`, etc.), the stream will return it from
its buffer.  If there are no more characters left in the buffer,
it will make a `read` request to the system, with the address
and the size of its buffer.  (On todays systems, I would be
surprised to see a buffer of less than 1K.)  What the system
does with it will depend on what the file descriptor designates:

a file

The system will copy bytes from the current position in the
file, until it has filled the buffer or reached end of file.  It
returns the number of bytes it copies (or -1, if there is an
error).

a keyboard

For keyboards, the system maintains an internal buffer of
its own, and reads line by line.  This buffer will only be
considered "ready" when the user presses enter; before that, the
system will simply not return from the `read`.  This allows the
system to implement line editing; e.g. processing things like
a backspace.  When you hit enter, the system adds the (system
specific) new line sequence to the buffer, and returns with the
number of characters it has copied into the buffer.  (Thus, not
0, since there is the new line.)  This procedure can be modified
in two ways: both Unix and Windows have a special characters
(control-D under Unix, control-Z under Windows) which tells the
system to return immediately from the read, with whatever the
buffer contains at the moment.  If you're at the start of
a line, the buffer contains nothing, the `read` returns
0 characters read, and the stream treats it as an end of file.
And if the stream buffer size is less than the number of characters in
the line (because you've calmly typed in 100000 characters
without a new line), `read` will return the maximum that will
fit in the buffer, and the next `read` will return immediately
with the rest of the line (or the next n `read` will return
immediately, until the entire line has been read).

a pipe

The system will wait until either there are as many
characters as requested in the pipe, or there are no more
processes left with the pipe open for write.  It will then copy
the number of characters requested (or less, of the write side
is closed), and return the number copied.

If the `read` indicates an error, the stream will set `badbit`;
if the `read` returns 0 characters read, the stream will treat
it as end of file.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. So basically the reason that cin waits is because the system still has the control waiting for the user to flush the input buffer?

Comment: @Veritas Yes.  Basically, `std::cin` (or any input file) calls into the OS to read; beyond that, it is up to the OS.  And what the OS supports can be quite complicated.

Comment: Alright one last thing. I recall reading that eof is detected when the system returns 0 bytes to the program. So do input streams request a buffer from the system, operate on it until they reach it's end and then request another one until they detect eof?

Comment: That's about it.  Streams are normally buffered.  Under Unix, if there is nothing in the buffer of the stream (and that is the initial state), then the stream will do a `read` of the length of the buffer.  If the file descriptor designates a file, the system will copy the bytes from the file into the buffer, stopping when it encounters end of file, or has copied n bytes, and it returns the number of bytes transferred.  If it is a keyboard, the system will not return from `read` until it has read a complete line, and the newline character, at least will be present in the buffer.

Comment: And the convention for `read` is that it returns the number of bytes actually transferred into the buffer: 0 means end of file (there were no more bytes), and -1 an error, with the error code in `errno`.  Windows uses different conventions for transmitting the information, but it comes out to the same: if there is no error, 0 bytes transferred means end of file.

Comment: I might add that if the input is a pipe, the system will not return until it has transferred all of the bytes requested (filled the buffer), or there are no more writers open on the pipe (which will result in eof if there are not already bytes in the pipe).

Comment: Alright thanks a lot for your help! You deserve each and every upvote! By the way you may want to add some of this info to the actual answer. It wouldn't change much but it would be more accessible to others that may be interested in the question.

Answer (score 0):

A std::istream might have a limited amount of data (a file on a hard drive, ...) or an unlimited amount of data (a sensor, ..., interactive user input). In addition there might be a special character representing EOF.

An interactive input from a console/terminal is an infinite input. Unless a special character is entered (Linux: ctl-d), the stream never reaches EOF.

A non interactive input from a pipe will (should/might) end in a EOF.

Comment: ctl-d under Linux is a bit special; it tells the system to return the current state of its buffer, without waiting for enter.  If there are already characters in the buffer, it will not be interpreted as end of file.  (Windows behaves similarly with clt-z.)